# Grouping 24 hours time by range

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I have a number of rows that are in 24 hour format like this

[image]

What i would like is to have a format like this one

```
+------+------+----------+
| from | to   | count(*) |
+------+------+----------+
| 0000 |  0100|        3 |
| 0100 | 0200 |        4 |
|  0200| 0300 |        2 |
| 0300 | 0400 |        1 |
+------+------+----------+
```

I have tried this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) `count`,
       100*FLOOR(the_amount/100) `from`,
       100*FLOOR(the_amount/100)+99 `to`
  FROM r_data
 where transaction_type = 'send'
 GROUP BY FLOOR(the_amount/100) ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

but this gives only one row.How should i write a query to group my time that is in 24 hour format?.

Comment: Just group by hour (the_time), unless the_time is a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  LPAD(100*FLOOR(24_hour_time/100),4,0) AS `from`,
  LPAD(100*FLOOR(24_hour_time/100) + 100,4,0) AS `to`,
  COUNT(*) AS `count`
FROM
  r_data
WHERE
  transaction_typ = 'send'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 24_hour_time;
```

But it will only show you "populated hours".